# Why .splice() method deletes elements of different indexes?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, splice

This is my first question on stackoverflow, I am new :) learning JS. I have a question. I wrote this function:

```
function inverseSlice(items, a, b) {
  return items.splice(a, b);
}
inverseSlice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2, 4)
(4) [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Why this function returns last 4 digits, when according to docs on MDN (which I read 10 times already :P) splice() method should remove here only 2 middle ones (3, 4)? It should return [1, 2, 5, 6]. Am I right? Thank You for all Your help :)

Comment: Did you check what [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) does and more specifically *what it returns*?

Comment: you get the deleted items of the array. please see in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#return_value).

Comment: Wooow, thanks guys for super quick answer :) sorry for my overlook, heh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing exactly what it advertises, it "returns an array containing the deleted elements."

```js
function inverseSlice(items, a, b) {
  return items.splice(a, b);
}

let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

// Deletes 4 entries starting at index 2,
// or in other words [3,4,5,6] are snipped
inverseSlice(array, 2, 4);

console.log(array);
```

Unless you keep a reference to the array you're passing in you'll never observe anything about how it ends up, you'll only get the deleted elements.

Answer (score 1):

`splice` will

- Mutate the original array: remove N items, where N is the third parameter, starting from the start index (first parameter) to the number specified (so here, it'll remove indicies 2 through 5 from the array; indicies 2, 3, 4, and 5, a total of 4 get removed)
- Return the removed elements - so, here, that's `[3, 4, 5, 6]`.

The original array is now `[1, 2]`, but you're logging what was returned by `.splice`, not the original array.

If you wanted `[1, 2, 5, 6]`, you'd want to specify 2 for the 3rd argument (2 items to remove), and then log the original array:

```js
function inverseSlice(items, a, b) {
  return items.splice(a, b);
}
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const removedItems = inverseSlice(arr, 2, 2);

console.log(arr);
console.log(removedItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are confused about is the arguments to splice, The **two arguments that you pass to splice** are not the start and end index but the **start index and the count of items to be deleted**.

Hence in your example it deleted items from 2 to 5 index and returned you the resultant array i.e `[3, 4, 5, 6]`

As per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#parameters):

> **Syntax:**
>
> ```
> let arrDeletedItems = arr.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - Start : The index at which to start changing the array.
> - deleteCount: n integer indicating the number of elements in the array to remove from start.
> - item1, item2, ... : The elements to add to the array, beginning from start. If you do not specify any elements, splice() will only remove
>   elements from the array.